# Relative import problem with python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

First of all, I have look through a lot of question-answer regarding this issue but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

---

I am on Python 3.7.9 and my file structure looks as in the following

```
generator/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    summarygenerator/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
        summary_generator.py
```

---

The summary_generator.py looks like

```
from summarygenerator.utils import solver

def sum_gen():
   pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
   sum_gen()
```

With this approach, from the '**generator**' directory I am able to run main.py with:

```
python main.py
```

and summary_generator.py with

```
python -m summarygenerator.summary_generator
```

However, when I would like to run summary_generator.py from the **generator/summarygenerator** directory then I face with:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named summarygenerator`

Relative imports as in the below doesn't solve the issue as well.

```
from .utils import solver
```

Comment: add the following code at the top of the utils and summarygenerator and try:
`import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))`
and then import module like you have done already
`from summarygenerator.utils import solver`

Comment: This is actually quite a bad habit to get into, modifying the system path like this could lead to all sorts of issues. It's better to append to the `PYTHONPATH` variable instead.

Comment: have you tried `from generator.summarygenerator.utils import solver`?  the partial success you are seeing is that the current directory is always considered to be on the Python path.  So it "sees" the summarygenerator module, but nothing else.  Is the overall directory even on the Python path?  can you `import generator` from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python modules are meant to be run from the parent directory of their root
package. So the correct way of running the scripts would be (starting from the generator directory):

```
$ cd ..
$ python -m generator.main
$ python -m generator.summarygenerator.summary_generator
```

The imports are meant to work out of the box and you can even use relative imports. Now you seem to want to be able to run the python script with the same code from two different locations out of the box (with the same code). That is not supported and indeed makes no sense. In the imports case it would mean that python should be able to record the name of the module in *two* different ways and everything (all other module names) should work with both names. Or take the (simpler) case of defining relative paths in your file (like `open('some_file')`) - this is doomed if the file is run in two ways. In both cases the problem is the change in the current working directory - the directory the script is run from is set as the current working directory relative to which paths (including module paths) are calculated. You can make this "run me from whatever folder" work by messing with the current working dir and creating even more subtle bugs - or (and this is the answer I think) stop trying to be able to run the same script from different folders, write the imports so they work with the commands above which is the recommended way of running a python script (so all documentation on imports assume this way of running it)

Answer (score 1):

So, that error is pretty clear in that you haven't declared a module named `summarygenerator`. Since `utils` resides in the same module as your `summary_generator` code, you could try just doing a direct import like below, since [Python's module search path starts with the current directory](https://realpython.com/lessons/module-search-path/)

```
from utils import solver
```

Other ways to address your issue, typically when `utils` would be in a different module would be to package your application and declare your modules explicitly or look at setting the `PYTHONPATH` to include your desired modules.

Comment: Actually what you suggest will not work (directly importing as usual). With that approach when you call the packages from the outer directory it can't find the 'utils' and will throw 'ModuleNotFoundError'.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't realise you wanted to call it from the outer directory as well. In that case, I would say, either look into packaging it up, since it's a command line tool. Otherwise, the `PYTHONPATH` is your best route.